# Latest OS X 10.8.3 Memory Leak

Tags: macos, memory, memory-leak

I have 8Gb memory installed. When I quit all of my programs i have free 500Mb. After purge command this value increased to 700Mb. Where is my 8Gb? It is marked as WIRED...

Reboot helps but only for 1 hour...

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose the problem - this could be almost anything. What purge command? Which programs?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier What information you need? Just Ask me... `purge` - is default terminal program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity Monitor has columns that are not displayed unless you ask for them. Try "View -> Columns -> Real Memory".  If you show All Processes, you may be able to find the process(es) that are tying up memory.  You can click on a column to sort the results. My current machine has process 0, kernel_task, at 1.55 GB.  Firefox has 1.04 GB.  Surprised me.  Private Memory could also be a culprit.